# Use a button to toggle content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, toggle

Here is what I have so far...

http://codepen.io/john84/pen/FctgH

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
      <p>BOTTOM CONTENT</p>
        <div class="box">
          <p>TOP CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: all: 0.8s ease;
  transitions: all 0.8s ease;
  background: rgba(151, 251, 152, 1);
}
.outer:hover > .box {
  margin: 0;
}
.box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

...can I make that transition happen using a button toggle as opposed to the hover? There will be multiple instances of this on the page if that makes a difference.

FYI - there is currently no JS used but I am not opposed to using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a easy and fast solution:
**Jquery:**

```
$('.outer').click(function(e) {
    $('.box').toggleClass('show');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.show {
    margin: 0;
}
```

and **exlcude** this part of your css:

```
.outer:active > .box {
  margin: 0;
}
```

#### See JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fpxLau4x/)

Hope it helps...
Sorry if my english is bad...

Comment: This one works perfectly. However, is there a way to make it so that multiple instances of this would work on a single page without doing writing a script for each instance?

Comment: @John Yep, just add a `.children()` selector in the script, like: `$(this).children('.box')`. This works very well, but the `.outer` div needs to be parent of `.box` div. [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fpxLau4x/2/) for the updated JsFiddle.

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver. One final thing and I apologize for not bringing it up earlier; can I use a button just underneath each div to show and hide the "top content"?

Comment: @John Yep again! The button needs to be inside the `.container` div and you can use the `.prev()` selector in JQuery. However, it's necessary you change the `position: relative` from `.container` to `.outer`. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/fpxLau4x/3/

Comment: You rock, gio_nicol! Thanks again for the help, I would have racked my brain for months just to figure that out on my own.

Comment: @John It's very nice to know I helped you! Good luck in your projects! :)